How to merge Headers of index and other headers to one row of headers and add numeric index as single index
I currently have this type of a df with 2 headers
        client case  client payment  payment number
client  
foo            1             200               1
boo            1             250               2
moo            1             225               3


and I would like a numeric index and merge the header into one single header and for the previous index to be the first column:
  client  client case  client payment  payment number
0  foo            1             200               1
1  boo            1             250               2
2  boo            1             225               3

df.columns = [c[0] + c[1] for c in df.columns]
this did not work for me, nor dit several set_index options

df.reset_index()

can you provide result of print(df.to_dict()) in post?
